# How do I target landscape and portrait orientation for mobile devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, stylesheet

I am using bootstrap to build a client's site and I have come unstuck when trying to target landscape and portrait orientation on mobile in order to add some specific styles for both viewports. How do I target portrait and landscape orientation for mobile styles? I need to add specific styles at 320px breakpoint and certain styles at 480px breakpoint. With my current media queries this is not working Currently in my stylesheet  I have the following:

```
/* portrait phones */
@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* Styles */
}

/* landscape phones */
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (orientation:landscape) {
/* Styles */
    }
```

If I put styles in for landscape however I don't think they are being picked up. Every time I make a change and then refresh my Iphone I don't see any difference. Im thinking maybe my media queries are wrong? If there is a better way to target mobile states I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: for this kind of situations use CSS-Mobile first frameworks like Foundation zurb http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.html,   Very easy to use don't get confuse..

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I figured out the problem in the meantime. in my header I had initial-scale=1 or something like that which is why I was having problems I have since removed that and used media query `/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px)` now when i flip my phone from portrait to landscape it works! (:

Comment: Cool happie coding.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue in the end by adding a max-width to my 321px media query and was able to target both landscape and portrait mobile orientation. I also found in my header I had: `initial-scale=1` which seemed to be causing the problem and after removing it I was able to target the mobile breakpoints I needed.

```
/*Portrait phones */
@media (max-width:320px){}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 480px) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
@media (orientation: portrait) and (max-width: 400px) {Fooobar}

@media (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 400px) {foobar}
```

Comment: Awesome!! exactly what i needed ( the landscape orientation ). Learnt another thing about CSS today